# Selecting double vs single letter at end of string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to write a MySQL select statement where I am trying to select values based on the last letter or letters of a string. The problem is... these values have double letters at the end of the string and I am not able to differentiate between them when getting results.

For example... I have the following 2 values in a table

```
1. Mens 3's AA
2. Mens 3's A
```

The query I am currently using returns both values when I only want to return #2 above. Here is the query:

```
SELECT divisions.div_id, divisions.div_lname
FROM divisions
WHERE LEFT(divisions.div_lname,1) = "M"
AND divisions.div_lname LIKE '%3%'
AND RIGHT(divisions.div_lname,1) = 'A'
ORDER BY divisions.div_nop, divisions.div_order
```

I really need to understand the best approach for selecting 1 but not the other when I have values that contain duplicate letters at the end of the string. Is there a regex approach that would work?

Comment: always check the last 2 characters..  when SPACE A... vs AA...  Or better yet, find the last space and take everything to the right of it to compare.  and best yet... Normalize the data... and this problem goes away.

Comment: right(divisions.div_lname,2) = ' A' ?

Comment: `right(_,<n>)` extracts the suffix of length `n`, so try to add the condition `AND right(divisions.div_lname,2) <> 'AA'` or `AND right(divisions.div_lname,2) <> ' A'` to your where clause, depending on whether you want to exclude an unwanted pattern or to ascertain a desired suffix.

Comment: Note to all: `LIKE` does NOT use regexes. It is more like glob.

Comment: Replace `AND RIGHT(divisions.div_lname,1) = 'A'` with `AND divisions.div_lname REGEXP '[^A]A$'`

Comment: If you need to check for a single `A` at the end, not preceded with any word character, use a word boundary `[[:<:]]`: `AND divisions.div_lname REGEXP '[[:<:]]A$'`

Comment: I wanted to say "thank you" to everyone who took the time to provide feedback to my question. This board always amazes me with the overall breadth and depth of activity. It's fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using SUBSTRING_INDEX() like this, it'll return the last chunk after the space..so it won't return rows that have 'AA'..and only return row with 'A'

```
SELECT divisions.div_id, divisions.div_lname
FROM divisions
WHERE LEFT(divisions.div_lname,1) = "M"
AND divisions.div_lname LIKE '%3%'
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(divisions.div_lname,' ',-1) = 'A'
ORDER BY divisions.div_nop, divisions.div_order
```

Comment: After testing against my various use cases and data sets, I have found Tin's solution has solved my question. I had toyed with using the SUBSTRING function but was not aware of the SUBSTRING_INDEX variant. Not only did it solve my problem learned about a new function in the process. 

That said, Wiktor's second comment regarding a REGEX solution also works. 

Again... many thanks for the insight and direction!